# Replace HTML object with text when printing

Tags: html, object

I have the line below to show and inline PDF

```
<div id="pdf"><object data="foo.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</object></div>
```

Works perfectly, however when one prints the page I would like to replace the PDF with text.

Is there and easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

more on the comment;

you can have another div that is `display:none`

and display it only if media type is print and hide the div that is pdf.

```
@media print {
     #pdf{
        display:none;
     }
     #txt{
        display:inline;
     }
}
```

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/SQ9Pv/